# Runtime error :reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' for "198. House Robber"

Tags: c++, pointers, null, runtime

I practiced C++ coding for the `Problem #198` House Robber in Leetcode, below is the codes I wrote

[image]

but it shows

```
Runtime error: reference binding to the null pointer of type 'value_type'
```

when I tried to submit the solution. I check the codes again and again, but still unable to find the reason. Is anyone able to help me figure it out?

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: `f[1] = max(nums[0], nums[1]);`  -- Both `f[1]` and `nums[1]` are out of bounds when `n` is `1`.  When `n == 0` you have even more problems.